# Windows plugin to always show if a program was started with admin rights?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a software to explicitly show which programs have been started with admin rights on Windows 7?

Like by having the software adding a prefix ("Administrator") on other program's titlebar, or (better) add the "yellow and blue shield" on the program task bar icon?

---

I would like such thing because some programs are started with admin rights (sometimes because they are poorly written, and sometimes because I forgot I've run them from an administrator-privileged `cmd` prompt) and so, they disallow drag & dropping or custom shortcut bindings. Having a way to see wether these programs have "admin rights" would help me a lot.

Originally asked on https://superuser.com/questions/1211943/windows-plugin-option-to-always-show-if-a-window-program-was-started-with-admin but it seems there is no default-option to do so in Windows, so I will need a 3rd party software to do that.

Comment: The reverse can be done using AutoHotKey and the WinSetTitle command. It allows you to change the title of a window, but it fails if the application has administrator rights and leaves the title intact. If such an answer is useful for you, I can write an example script.

Comment: But does it require you to press a key to trigger the script?

Comment: Usually yes, but you can also configure other triggers, though not straightforwardly. Although not optimal for the task, one can use it if nothing else exists. [This answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/373172/291919) has an example.